# MySQL Identifying Connection Attempt

Tags: mysql, security, client

I'm seeing the following errors repeatedly in the error log file for our production MySQL server:

> [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'remote.appserver.com' (using
>   password: NO)

So, I know where the connection attempt is coming from, but I don't know how to track down the application trying to connect.  Is there any way to determine the application, program, client initiating the request?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not have a way to determine the information you're looking for (client attempting the connection). The only thing you will get from a direct connection attempt is the username and hostname (as noted above).

MySQL doesn't utilize or pass User-Agent-like data in that manner.